# What happens to instance variables in a activity class after minimizing and maximizing the application

Tags: android

What happens to instance variables in a activity class after minimizing and maximizing the application when on that particular activity. I couldn't find a straight forward answer to this question. Also will variables that hold references to expensive resources like a DB connection be treated differently?

Comment: For DB Connection you need to close connection when application is on pause and re-open while onResume

Comment: the instance variable don't loose any data when minimized. Variable with class scope will be cleared on destroying the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on any behaviour you observe, instead be sure to implement the [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) correctly. Whenever the `onDestroy` method is called, all instance variables will be gone.

Comment: but if onDestroy is called then if the activity was to be started again the onCreate would be called yes? So initializing the values in onCreate should be sufficient correct?

Comment: Yes, this is sufficient.

Comment: so unless and until onDestroy is called the instance variables will hold all their values?

Comment: Yes, they will be valid as long as the activity instace is around. The framework takes care to call `onDestroy` before.